# Youtube No-Cookie Tracking

Tags: cookies, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

As part of the GDPR, I'm trying to disable cookie tracking coming from Youtube videos embedded in our site. I used the 'no-cookie' approach on the host option. However, i still see cookies coming from the Youtube domain such as LOGIN_INFO, PREF, SID and many more when I play the videos.

Is there something that I'm missing, or disabling tracking does not necessarily means no cookie are generated from Youtube domain at all?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the host to `youtube-nocookie.com` ? This will stop cookies being set only until a user presses the play button.

Comment: Yes Vanita, we are using the youtube-nocookie.com as a host. I forgot to mention that we are using the mediaelementjs plugin to render our youtube player. I have tried just embedding pure youtube iframe with -nocookie url, and it does not set cookies. Cookies are only being set if yt videos rendered using the mediaelementjs plugin

Answer (score 0):

It just means, that no cookie are sent before the visitor clicks on the videos play button. So you should add an information under the video that as soon as they click the button they accept the data privacy rules of Google / YouTube.